# How to plot percentage changes, cumulative sums, standard deviations in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

In python, percentage changes, cumulative sums, std deviations can be plotted, using the following code snippet:

```py
df=quandl.get('EURONEXT/XYZ.4')
df_changes = df.pct_change(periods=1)
df_cumsum = df_changes.cumsum()
df_filled = df.asfreq('D', method='ffill')
df_returns = df_filled.pct_change()
df_std = df_returns.window=30,minperiod=30).std()
df_changes.plot()
df_cumsum.plot()
df_std.plot()
```

Please guide me in doing the same thing in Julia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cumsum, see [Cumulative sum of a column in Julia DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044861/cumulative-sum-of-a-column-in-julia-dataframe). For pct_change, see [Julia DataFrames equivalent of pandas pct_change()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325202/julia-dataframes-equivalent-of-pandas-pct-change) For resampling, see [Resampling a DataFrame to hourly 15min and 5min periods in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816813/resampling-a-dataframe-to-hourly-15min-and-5min-periods-in-julia) And for the rolling functions, etc (probably overlapping the previous items), see https://github.com/dysonance/Indicators.jl For plotting see https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl